# Jenkins trigger conditional build steps in shell?

Tags: bash, jenkins

I am using Jenkins as a server to run cron jobs that are conditional on the success of other jobs. These can be run as multiple execute shell steps. I am specifically wondering if there is a way to make an execute shell step contingent on the exit status of the previous execute shell step.

Comment: you can use $? status as loop condition for each command as iteration.. ex: `while $? -eq 0 ; exec command`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This **is** the default behaviour. Each build step, such as **"Execute Shell"** step, returns an exit code (last command). If that is `0`, the next build step is executed. If that is not `0`, Jenkins "FAILS" the build, and skips straight to post-build steps.

If your shell returns `0` on success, and everything else is a failure, just put several "Execute Shell" build steps one after another.